# How to animate snowman without third party libraries?

Tags: c++

I have the following code that is just some cout statements that output an image of a **cool** snowman
This is something i like to show to novice programmers to show them how cool programming can be.
I wanna take this a step further and show some animation, but after some research, i realized i'd need to download some external programs like turboc++ for animations in c++.

Is there  way to make the snow animated falling down without downloading anything? i can run this in C++17 if necessary for some advanced headers, as long as i dont have to download anything.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  std::cout << "    *                   *        \n";
  std::cout << "*        *                       \n";
  std::cout << " *                *            * \n";
  std::cout << "      *     *                    \n";
  std::cout << "                      *          \n";
  std::cout << "*         *                 *    \n";
  std::cout << "     *        *     *            \n";
  std::cout << "           HHHHHHH        *      \n";
  std::cout << " *         HHHHHHH               \n";
  std::cout << "     *   HHHHHHHHHHH    *     *  \n";
  std::cout << "         *   @ @   *             \n";
  std::cout << "        *     ^     *            \n";
  std::cout << "  *       *       *         *    \n";
  std::cout << "         ||| * * |||             \n";
  std::cout << "         * ======== *            \n";
  std::cout << "       *      O       *          \n";
  std::cout << "      *       O        *         \n";
  std::cout << "      *       O        *         \n";
  std::cout << "       *              *          \n";
  std::cout << "           *   *   *             \n";

  return 0;
```

Comment: Well, you could store the initial snowman as an multidimensional array, and for each iteration find every asterisk and shift them down by one row before displaying the array. A problem with this approach, however, is that your snowman is made up of asterisks as well, so shifting down "all" asterisks would change the snowman too. Also note that you'd need to somehow "separate" each iteration (probably with some sort of user input) so that the iterations don't all execute at once.

Comment: @Telescope thats true...maybe i can replace the snowman asterisk with `0`...would be "built different" lol

Comment: It depends. Are you hoping to animate it in place or draw a series of images with different snowflakes? A series is easy, keep two buffers, one with the snowman an one with the snowflakes. Between drawing move the snowflakes then combine the buffers either as a third one you then print or on the fly by looking up the data in both and combining them. If you want to do it in place then you will need to use platform specific APIs to do so.

Comment: @RetiredNinja id be fine with a series of images if keeping it in place requires installations. however, if the API is just a call, so no downloads required (because i want to run this on online compilers on the go) then thats fine as well...but what kinda API's? essentially, im just hoping for some animation really, instead of this still image

Comment: The online compilers I know of have pretty bad display capabilities. *shrug*

Comment: @RetiredNinja this one https://www.onlinegdb.com/ has been my reliable go to online compiler. it has pretty good display from what ive seen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick program I wrote that I think does what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

bool update(vector <string> &snowman){
    bool ret = false;
    int row_len = snowman[0].size();
    for(int i = 0; i < row_len; ++i){
        if(snowman.back()[i] == '*'){ret = true; snowman.back()[i] = ' ';}
    }

    for(int i = snowman.size()-2; i >= 0; --i){
        for(int j = 0; j < row_len; ++j){
            if(snowman[i][j] == '*'){
                char temp = snowman[i+1][j];
                if(temp == 'H' || temp == '0'){
                    snowman[i][j] = ' ';
                    continue;
                }

                swap(snowman[i][j], snowman[i+1][j]);
                ret = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    vector <string> snowman = {
        "    *                   *        ",
        "*        *                       ",
        " *                *            * ",
        "      *     *                    ",
        "                      *          ",
        "*         *                 *    ",
        "     *        *     *            ",
        "           HHHHHHH        *      ",
        " *         HHHHHHH               ",
        "     *   HHHHHHHHHHH    *     *  ",
        "         0   @ @   0             ",
        "        0     ^     0            ",
        "  *       0       0         *    ",
        "         ||| 0 0 |||             ",
        "         0 ======== 0            ",
        "       0      O       0          ",
        "      0       O        0         ",
        "      0       O        0         ",
        "       0              0          ",
        "           0   0   0             ",
    };

    do{
        this_thread::sleep_for(0.5s);
        system("clear");
        for(string &item : snowman){
            cout << item << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    while(update(snowman));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: nice!! btw it may be worth mentioning this requires C++14 for `0.5s`.
also, it ends after snow falls down. how to keep it animating (snow falling down) until key is pressed?

Comment: @Cataster I'm not sure how to write the program so that it'll keep animating until a key is pressed. Somebody else please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you'd need some external library to achieve that.

Comment: i see, you're right. `windows.h` required for `GetKeyState` :/ ok what about just animate infinitely and of course user can stop program with `stop` button